# DirectionsRenderer overwrite the Marker when rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-google-maps, react-google-maps-api

I'm working on setting up a tracking system so customers can see where their deliveries are in real-time. I managed to setup for marker destination and pickup location along with route path toward it. The issues is when I tried to render it, Two Custom Markers being overwrote/overlapped by the existing two (including the one with bike icon). Here is pic of what happening.

[image: pic of marker being overlap by Direction Renderer Marker]

My Question is there any way to show custom Markers instead of DirectionRenderer Marker? Here is my implementation.

```js
"use client";
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import { GoogleMap, useJsApiLoader,Marker,DirectionsRenderer } from '@react-google-maps/api';
import { DeliveryData } from '@/lib/types';
const containerStyle = {
  width: '400px',
  height:'400px '
};

let directionsService: google.maps.DirectionsService;

function MapContainer({ deliveryData }: { deliveryData: DeliveryData }) {
  const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
    id: 'google-map-script',
    googleMapsApiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY || ""
  });
  
  const pickupCoordinates = {
    lat: -33.8827923,
    lng: 151.1959758
  }

  const deliveryCoordinates = {
    lat: -33.8876642,
    lng: 151.2086783
  }
  
  const [deliveryGuyPosition, setDeliveryGuyPosition] = useState(deliveryCoordinates);
  const [directions, setDirections] = useState<google.maps.DirectionsResult | null>(null);
  
  const [_, setMap] = React.useState<google.maps.Map | null>(null)

  const onLoad = React.useCallback(function callback(map: google.maps.Map) {
    const bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    bounds.extend(deliveryCoordinates);
    bounds.extend(pickupCoordinates);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);    
    changeDirection(pickupCoordinates, deliveryCoordinates);
    setMap(map)
  }, []);

  const changeDirection = (origin: any, destination: any) => {
    directionsService.route(
      {
        origin: origin,
        destination: destination,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
      },
      (result, status) => {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          // Change the state of directions to the result of direction service
          setDirections(result);
        } else {
          console.error(`Error fetching directions ${result}`);
        }
      }
    );
  };

  const onUnmount = React.useCallback(function callback() {
    setMap(null)
  }, [])

  return (isLoaded && <GoogleMap mapContainerStyle={containerStyle} onLoad={onLoad} onUnmount={onUnmount}>
      
      {directions !== null && <DirectionsRenderer directions={directions} />}
      <Marker position={pickupCoordinates} title="pick up loaction"
        icon={'images/destination.png'}
      />
      <Marker position={deliveryGuyPosition} title="Delivery Guy"
      icon={'images/delivery.png'}
      />
      </GoogleMap>)

}

export default React.memo(MapContainer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not particularly solution I fond of but I found a way to overcome the issue. The `markeroptions`in DirectionsRender not allowed to style [individually](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions#DirectionsRendererOptions). Therefore I put the transparent background as in option to hide it. For example it would be something like this

```js
 <GoogleMap mapContainerStyle={containerStyle} onLoad={onLoad} onUnmount={onUnmount}>
      {directions !== null && <DirectionsRenderer directions={directions}
      options={{
        markerOptions: {
          icon: "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8z8BQDwAEhQGAhKmMIQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==",
        }
    }} 
      />}
      <Marker position={pickupCoordinates} title="pick up location" icon={'images/destination.png'} />
      <Marker position={deliveryGuyPosition} title="Delivery Guy" icon={"images/delivery.png"} />
</GoogleMap>
```